# Как развернуть war на tomcat вручную?

Tags: tomcat

У меня есть `war` который я хочу развернуть вручную. Я положил свой `war` в webapps и из папки `bin` запустил `sh startup.sh` Tomcat запустился с таким сообщением:

```
$ sh startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

И на `http://localhost:8080/` у меня открывается сам tomcat, и в `webapps` 
 появилась папка с таки же именем как и `war` но по аддресу сервлетов не по имени war-ника ничего не открывается.

Что необходимо сделать чтобы Tomcat запустил мой `war` архив? Разве tomcat автоматически не сканирует `webapps` и не запускает то что там лежит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всё правильно сделали. Посмотрите файлы в каталоге {tomcat}/logs : catalina.out и localhost.[data].log . Там скорее всего указана ошибка при запуске WAR файла.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ: удалить содержимое папки *\webapps\ROOT*, а затем распаковать в папку *\webapps\ROOT* содержимое вашего веб-приложения (`war`). Для удобства можно настроить в среде разработки сборку приложения прямо в папку *\webapps\ROOT*.